# How to return an httpclient response as a variable through a function instead of an observer/promise

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have read up a lot and I understand that my question might be a duplicate of many other questions but I can't seem to find/understand any of the answers I found.

I am trying to create a function that will return the response of the backend from an asynchronous call, and not a prommise or an observable. I have tried these methods but neither of them are working. Please help me understand how I can get the response to be returned as a variable.

```
  callQuery() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.httpclient.get(MyUrl).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }

  callQuery() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpclient.get(MyUrl).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    })['__zone_symbol__value'];
  }

  async callQuery() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpclient.get(MyUrl).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }
```

So `console.log(callQuery())` keeps returning an object called `ZoneAwarePromise`. And inside this object there is actually a key called `__zone_symbol__value` which holds my response. But I don't know how to access it (for example the second function above does not work as intended).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to reflect your needs. If you think I did it bad, don't hesitate to tell me (or cancel the changes yourself)

Comment: @trichetriche Ah thanks man! I just changed the title, because your title wasn't really asking a question anymore? But I appreciate the other changes!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Observables as they're way more developped than promises.

But since you asked, here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hea8bu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) showing you how to create promises from observables.

Stop creating promises on your own, and rely on the Observable itself :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.createPromiseFromObservable(this.createDelayedObservable()).then(() => {
    console.log('Promise fullfilled');
  });
}

createDelayedObservable() {
  return of(true)
    .pipe(delay(500));
}

createPromiseFromObservable(obs: Observable<any>) {
  return obs.toPromise();
}
```

**EDIT** New [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9phs2t?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with async and await :

```js
// Declare the function as async to use await
async ngOnInit() {
  // awaits for the result, then prints it in console.
  // Remove this.createDelayedObservable() and use this.http.get(...) for real HTTP calls
  const res = await this.createPromiseFromObservable(this.createDelayedObservable());
  console.log(res);
}

// simulate an HTTP call taking 500ms to complete. Can be deleted.
createDelayedObservable(): Observable<any> {
  return of(true)
    .pipe(delay(500));
}

// Transforms an observable into a promise to be used with await
createPromiseFromObservable(obs: Observable<any>): Promise<any> {
  return obs.toPromise();
}
```

Comment: What would the equivalent be of `console.log(callQuery())` or `myVar = callQuery()` from my example?

Comment: `console.log(this.createPromiseFromObservable(this.createDelayedObservable()))`. But you're logging a promise, which is kind of useless. You should log the result of the promise once completed to see it working.

Comment: I really don't see how your answer is helping me man. Check out my answer. Also, please don't use complex stuff when it isn't related to the answer (like I don't understand what .pipe(delay(500)) does. Can't you just use a setTimeout for this example?....maybe if you can give me a more practical example I will understand your answer. The way you are doing it (with .then()) I might as well just use .subscribe...right? I'm not fighting, I just don't understand how this helps.

Comment: My answer transforms Observables to Promises, which fullfills your title `Return Promise HttpClient Subscribe Response`. You make an HTTP call, it is transformed into a promise. This isn't "complex stuff", this is RxJS basics. No, I can't use a timeout, because they haven't the same purpose. A timeout shifts the instruction to the end of the stack, whereas delay delays an observable. `then` is for promises, `subscribe` is for observables. They are **not** the same thing. I think you're getting lost on all of that, please explain exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad, I think the confusion comes from my title. I don't necessarily want a promise. I would just like to create a function that does a call and returns the result. So that I can say `MyVar = thecallfunction()` and `MyVar` will then me the result from the call.

Comment: @FreddyBonda I have made an edit to my answer, this should fullfill this requirement. I also added a little bit of comments to explain briefly what each function does.

Answer (score 0):

The way I feel like my question is solved the best:

```
  async callQuery() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpclient.get(MyUrl).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }

  async WhateverFunction() {
    ...
    const MyVar = await this.callQuery());
    console.log(MyVar);
    ...
  }
```

Comment: glad my answer could help you ;)

Answer (score -1):

what about this ?

```
const callQuery = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpclient.get(MyUrl).subscribe((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }

const getResult = async function() {
    const response = await callQuery();
    return response['__zone_symbol__value'];
}
```

Comment: free downvote without any explanation : | thank you for helping me to improve

Comment: I am the one who downvoted, simply look at my answer and you'll understand. As a SOF rule, consider doing that everytime you have a downvote. If you think it is not justified, then indeed, post this kind of request as you did.

Comment: Am I saying it's not justified ? I was just asking for a way to understand why this answer is bad

Comment: And I'm telling you look at my answer, and that as a general rule, before being sassy about a downvote, you should read other questions. Once done, if you think the upvote isn't justified, then you can ask for explanations. Do you understand on your own why your answer is bad after reading my answer ?

Comment: Down vote is when an answer can't help/is not useful, not when it's not the best according to you mate.
My answer just sticks itself to the question.

Comment: Downvotes is when the user sees fit. And I see fit. Your answer relies on private properties that should **not** be accessed, adds a complicated and unecessary layer of code, is not proven to work since you didn't provide a sandbox to test it, and isn't even taking advantage of the `Observable.prototype.fromPromise` method. I would downvote 5 times if I could, but I can't. So please, stop the sass (again), and learn to accept criticism.

Comment: I do not agree. In this case, Nathan's answer was more helpful and easier to understand than yours. Yours is 4 parts of code. Your answer (truchetriche) is definitely more `adds a complicated and necessary layer of code` than Nathan's. My title probably caused the confusion, but there is no need to say someone is sassing when their answer is totally valid. Sometime I feel that experienced coders make things unnecessarily complicated....To me Nathan's answer is definitely less complicated and solves my problem (with some minor changes, which is why I posted my own answer)

Comment: @FreddyBonda I'm not experienced, I'm just coding properly. there is literally no difficulty in my code, it's a single function that transforms observables into promises. If you don't understand it, I really suggest you learn Typescript and Javascript. But if his answer helped you, good ! Just know that it's terrible practice and you should not do that. Anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: I did upvote but it doesn't show haha. But I upvoted both though. Thanks anyways guys :)